# How to use a string like a variable in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I´m a beginner in Visual Basic and I need some help.
I have the following:

```
Dim var1 As String = "test1"
Dim newvar As String = "var1"
Dim othervar As String = ""
```

How can I make the contents of `othervar` variable be "test1" using only the variable `newvar`? For example:

```
othervar=newvar
```

And the contents of the variable `othervar` be "test1".
How would one use a string as variable in Visual Basic?
I´m using Visual Studio Express 2012

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? This syntax you invented does not exist.

Comment: The nearest thing to what you are looking for is CallByName

Comment: "How can I make to the contents of othervar variable be "test1" using only the variable newvar?"  That depends on where `var1` is declared.  Is it a **local** variable in a method (with the other two variables)?...or is it declared at class/form level?

Comment: *CallByName() will only work if `var1` is declared as **Public** in a Class.  If that is not the case then you'd have to use **Reflection** to accomplish the task.

Comment: You can always store everything in a Dictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx but since you are a beginer, maybe that's not a good idea. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

As peterG mentioned, CallByName() can be used.  This however requires that the `var1` variable be declared as **Public** at **Class**(Form) level:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public var1 As String = "test1"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newvar As String = "var1"
        Dim othervar As String = CallByName(Me, newvar, CallType.Get)
        MessageBox.Show(othervar)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If `var1` is **Private** then you can use **Reflection** like this (it still must be a **Class** level variable):

```
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1

    Private var1 As String = "test1"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newvar As String = "var1"
        Dim FI As FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetField(newvar, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim othervar As String = FI.GetValue(Me)
        MessageBox.Show(othervar)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that if `var1` is a local variable then no method exists to retrieve its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner with VB, you may find this site useful: [Visual Basic Language Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbykd75d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to set a string variable to the same string another variable holds, you just use the syntax like you have already:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim var1 As String = "test1"
    Dim otherVar As String = var1

    Console.WriteLine(var1) 'test1
    Console.WriteLine(otherVar) 'test1

    var1 = "test2"

    Console.WriteLine(var1) 'test2 
    Console.WriteLine(otherVar) 'test1 (notice this did not change) 


End Sub

End Module
```