# Dynamically calling another variable name with another variable

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have the following lines of code:

```
    Dim ta = frmControllerScreen.Controls.Find("txtResponseA", True)
    If ta.Count > 0 Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = ta.First
        txtResponseA = txt.Text
    End If

    Dim tb = frmControllerScreen.Controls.Find("txtResponseB", True)
    If tb.Count > 0 Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = tb.First
        txtResponseB = txt.Text
    End If

    Dim tc = frmControllerScreen.Controls.Find("txtResponseC", True)
    If tc.Count > 0 Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = ta.First
        txtResponseC = txt.Text
    End If

    Dim td = frmControllerScreen.Controls.Find("txtResponseD", True)
    If td.Count > 0 Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = ta.First
        txtResponseD = txt.Text
    End If
```

So it's clear that I'm assigning a string to an A, B, C, D version of a variable. The goal is that I will be able to go ahead and call one of these values up and assign it to a textbox/label.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
    lblAutoChoice1.Text = ("txtResponse" & chrAvailableAnswers.Item(0).ToString.Trim)
```

But It's not exactly working. I attempted to use `.ToString` method on it but I'm only greeted with a `System.ToString[]` response during run time.

This would be easy to do in other languages, like PHP `$Somevariable$correctAnswer` for example to pull up `$SomevariableA` but I've yet to see an example of a variable variables in VB.

How do you create a variable variables (I believe is the proper name) in Visual Basic?

Comment: The comments were copy/paste from other parts of the code where the first line came from. Appreciate the helpful gesture @HansPassant

Comment: @JamesThorpe: With regard to using `Me.Controls.Find...` I'm now getting `System.Windows.Forms.Control[]` when I use the `Me.Controls.Find("txtResponse" & chrCorrectAnswer, True).ToString` handle. I didn't know that variables were treated as controls in VB.

Comment: They're not, I misread what you're after - you've just found the same control again...

Comment: Is this something that's possible in vb or should I just use case/switch instead and possibly remove this question?

Comment: It is possible...but this is usually an indication that the app was horribly designed.  You can get the value of the variable (based on a string) using [Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054284/2330053).

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Yes Reflection did it!  (Granted I did it in one line as opposed to declaring it and then using the declared value.) Still tempted to delete the question to the reputation back from the downvote however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from Idle_Mind's answer listed here:
[How to use a string like a variable in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037979/how-to-use-a-string-like-a-variable-in-visual-basic/20054284#20054284)

```
lblAutoChoice1.Text = Me.GetType.GetField("txtResponse" & chrAvailableAnswers.Item(0).ToString, _ 
BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(Me).ToString
```

This directly calls for `Imports System.Reflection` on being used as the top line, above the declaration of the `Class` of the form.